# Record AVAudioPlayer output using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, audio-recording

In my app the user plays a sound by pressing a button. There are several buttons which can be played simultaneously. The sounds are played using AVAudioPlayer instances. I want to record the output of these instances using AVAudioRecorder. I have set it all up and a file is created and records but when I play it back it does not play any sound. It is just a silent file the length of the recording. Does anyone know if there is a setting I am missing with AVAudioPlayer or AVAudioRecorder? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to record AVAudioPlayer output as input to AVAudioRecorder for recording. You can use audio buffer to store played files and save it to a file.

Comment: Can you share a link to the documentation that shows how to capture and store the AVAudioPlayer output buffer?

Comment: you can get refrence from here  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html

Comment: I'm going to have to work at a higher level and use something like * 
-(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*) captureOutput
        didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
        fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*) connection {

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easier to help if we saw your code.

You should also check out the following link to see if you have your AVAudioRecorder setup correctly: [How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)

Although that link shows how to setup a recording from the mic, it might still be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Was facing the same problem. Solved the problem by setting the AVAudioSession category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback mode. This is my working code:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
audioSession.delegate = self;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: nil];
```

Also make sure that the audio recording has been finished successfully by implementing:

```
   -(void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"Recording success:%@",flag ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

And check that you have added `<AVAudioSessionDelegate,AVAudioRecorderDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate>`

in your interface declaration.

Comment: Are you really doing the same thing as OP? (Record audio played with AVAudioPlayer:s)... it seems unlikely?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps, at least to look for something else.

I'm having the same issue here, I'm trying to record a mix of different sounds played at different times with a main track playing, what I found is that AVAudioRecorder records only from the mic, so it would work.

What I found, still have to read doc and test it, is the Audio Converter Services, I think that may work, but I have just read a few lines.

Once again, sorry to tell you, but you're looking the wrong way, I hope my answer helps

Comment: I was also missing the information what the recorder actually records in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html