# AVSpeechUtterance maximum volume really quiet and rate really fast

Tags: ios, ios7, text-to-speech

I was toying with adding speech cues to my app and was testing out AVSpeechUtterance in iOS 7, but the default speech rate is REALLY fast. The minimum speech rate is much more understandable. But the maximum volume value of 1 is soooo quiet! I tested it on my iPhone 4 with the volume turned all the way up. Something must be wrong or else how would this be usuable at all.

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
            NSString *mystring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Talk String Here %@",myObject.name];
            AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:mystring];
            [utterance setRate:AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate];
            [utterance setVolume:1];
            [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am experiencing the same problem, with the volume.

Comment: No I didn't, but I also haven't been working on it. Didn't seem like there was a good solution.

Comment: I posted what worked for me below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28922543/2578205 ). Maybe that will help?

Comment: @Glavin001 did you find any solution regarding volume ? I am stuck here very badly. Didn't find any soultion

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me   ( Swift 3.0 )

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()  
do {
  try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)  
} catch {   
  print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@tmr's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25794429/2578205) resolved this for me:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord  
                       withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker
                                       error:nil];
```

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time!! Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me, but when I connect my earphone to iPhone, only one side of earphone got sound, other side no sound. Any clue ?

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5 you can try this (add it before the synthesizer initialization):

```
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try? audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)
        try? audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.spokenAudio)
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8 differs to iOS 9:

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:utteranceString];
if([iOSVersionDetector isiOS9OrHigher])
    utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate;
else
    utterance.rate = 0.1f;
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 3** do (to fix the volume issue)

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed setting the mode to `AVAudioSessionModeDefault` or `AVAudioSessionModeSpokenAudio`:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeSpokenAudio)
```

Answer (score -2):

The rate is just a float value and the constants are provided for convenience. 
Try using [utterance setRate:AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate*.25];

Comment: `rate` is already a float value with range of 0.0 to 1.0 with `AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate` = 0.0 and `AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate` = 1.0. Since `AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate` is 0.0, multiplying it by any number is again 0.0.