# Change AVAudioPlayer output to speaker in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avaudioplayer

I have simple *AVAudioPlayer* in my iphone app, it works, but output should be phone speaker instead of headphone. I found [similiar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022992/how-to-get-avaudioplayer-output-to-the-speaker) here , but don't know how to 'translate' that to swift (*AudioSessionSetProperty* is confusing me)?

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: fileData, error: &playbackError) 
//fileData is url to file

if let player = audioPlayer{
    player.delegate = self

    if(player.prepareToPlay() && player.play()){
         println("Started playing the recorded audio")
    } else {
         println("Could not play the audio")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can understand how this is confusing as I just figured out the answer. So `AudioSessionSetProperty` was deprecated in iOS 7.

Add this:

```
session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, error: nil)
```

Make sure to call `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()` first.

Comment: for Swift 3-4 use the code below: 
try recordingSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)

Answer (score 17):

In Swift 3 or 4:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do {
    try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("audioSession error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

To avoid the `OSStatus` error -50 (mentioned by user462990 in the comments), `overrideOutputAudioPort` has to be called after setting the session category (code below).

```
do {
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("setCategory error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Could you please show this code integrated into Marko's code? I see an AVAudioPlayer in his code and an AVAudioSession in yours. How do these tie together? I tried adding your code into my project but keep getting errors.

Comment: I am using exactly this code but I'm getting an error on execution "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)" any ideas?

Comment: Here is a bit more of an explanation of what I found and what solved things for me when trying to implement a Navigation style prompt to car stereo or phone speaker if nothing connected to the phone.  Hope this helps someone else https://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/iphone-navigation-type-audio-prompts/

Answer (score 8):

try these function.they are work charming.

```
func SetSessionPlayerOn()
{
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    } catch _ {
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
    }
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    } catch _ {
    }
}
func SetSessionPlayerOff()
{
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    } catch _ {
    }
}
```

Comment: You Just Need To Call The SetSessionPlayerOn() Whenever You need.

Comment: Is there a way to change from speaker to built-in earpiece. I'm working on audio call but by default it's on speaker and there's no way I can manage to change.

Comment: Have You tried the above code with replacement of boolean value with their negative value? @Nij

Comment: Yes and that makes the speaker off. What i want is to activate earpiece which is near to front camera. 
**NOTE: I am using opentok library for making video/audio call.**

Comment: I also want to implement built-in earpiece on Opentok library for making audio call. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
  func SetEarSepeakerOn()
    {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        } catch _ {
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch _ {
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.none)
        } catch _ {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 5

```
    func setSessionPlayerOn() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord)
        } catch _ {
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch _ {

        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
        } catch _ {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may set the audio session defaults to the built-in speaker instead of the receiver during the session setup.

```
        do {
            // 1) Configure your audio session category, options, and mode
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat, options: [.defaultToSpeaker])
            // 2) Activate your audio session to enable your custom configuration
            try session.setActive(true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to set the audio session category and mode: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

All of these answers are either outdated or not permanent solutions.

As the docs describe, `If you’d prefer to permanently enable this behavior, you should instead set the category’s defaultToSpeaker option` like so:

```
try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.defaultToSpeaker])
```

`Setting this option routes to the speaker rather than the receiver if no other accessory such as headphones are in use.`