# Cocos 2d - sound effect/recording

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am a new to the cocos 2d framework. Now I want to write a small game which can receive my voice from the microphone of iPhone. So what knowledge do I need to have to do this and can you suggest any documents or links that I can read to learn?

Answer (score 0):

I found an article maybe useful to this.

http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/#comment-2699

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without the help of cocos 2d. You basically need to have a way to do audio capture. You can do it using AVAudioRecorder or using Audio Queue Services/Core Audio.

Here's a link on AVAudioRecorder
[How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)