# How to record an audio and play the recorded audio in Iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need to record an audio and play it in my app.As I am newbie I don't know how to implement it.Can anyone Please suggest me how to do this.

Thanks in advance,
Monish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AVAudioRecorder. The Question has already been answered here: [How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)

Playing the sound depends on your context. You can use AVAudioPlayer or CoreAudio if you want to go to a deeper level.