# Recording Audio from Mic in iPhone SDK 4.0?

Tags: iphone, audio

I would just like to know how to record audio from the iPhone's mic using the iPhone SDK. I tried using AQRecorder with SpeakHere but I can't get it to work. I would like to be able to record audio onto a file and then show play the audio back when the user requests it. Is there any easy way to do this? I just started iPhone development today so it would be nice if you could explain it in simple context.

Comment: I recently had the same question. This was a good starting point for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBS6qlNekco

This shows you how to record audio, then play it back. But it only uses a temporary file.