# How to record an audio file in .mp3 format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

I am using the following settings for recording audio file in .mp3 format using AVAudioRecorder.

```
NSDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],AVSampleRateKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3],AVFormatIDKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,nil];
```

But not able to record with these.
I searched a lot for this but wasn't able to get some relevant post.
Some posts say that it is not possible.If its not possible then why so?
Please answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Problem is `kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3` which is not supported by `AVAudioRecorder`.

Alternatively you can use `kAudioFormatAppleIMA4` for your recording purpose.

Finally you can write your own encoding logic to convert `kAudioFormatAppleIMA4` in to `MP3` Format.

The other supported encoding for Recording purpose are

```
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC   
kAudioFormatAppleLossless  
kAudioFormatAppleIMA4   
kAudioFormatiLBC 
kAudioFormatULaw 
kAudioFormatLinearPCM
```

For more info you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder) post of SO.

Comment: What encoding logic I have to write for converting to .mp3 files.I mean which classes can I use for this?