# iOS Audio Recording Size per Minute

Tags: iphone, ipad, size, voice, recording

A very high level question. I'm investigating the possibility of an app that would do 2-3 hr audio recordings at a time.

Does anyone know an proximate minute per MB rate for low (voice quality) level recordings? Now I know this can depend on lots of factors but I'm just looking for an approximate figure to see how feasible this can be for something 2-3 hrs long.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At CD quality (44.1k Samples/per second) for a single channel you get 158.76 M samples for a 1 hour stretch.  Multiply that by the sample size (say a 16 bit int) and you get 317.52 MB per hour per channel.  This is worst case, and I bet you could implement compression to reduce the physical size.

See SO questions like [how-to-record-voice-with-an-ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578598/how-to-record-voice-with-an-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the results for few encoding supported by iPhone. Size of audio file in KB of duration 10 sec.
kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC : 164,
kAudioFormatAppleLossless : 430,
kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 : 475,
kAudioFormatULaw : 889,
kAudioFormatALaw : 889,
Among these kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC is having smallest size

This answer I get from website.
Just for your reference.

Comment: Did you do this test in Mono or Stereo?