# How to record audio through an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, audio

I want to record audio in my iPhone app and once the audio is recorded I want a dialog box to open which asks for the filename.

And then I want to save the audio with that filename into my app. How can I do so?

Comment: i have added complete answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder

Answer (score 4):

try using AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioRecorder classes for audio recording and playback.Initially you have to establish an audio session using AVAudio session class

```
AVAudioSession *audioS =[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioS setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
[audioS setActive:YES error:&error];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],AVSampleRateKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];
```

and then initialize the recorder and player classes...Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Look at Apple's SpeakHere sample app, available on their iOS developer site.

Answer (score 2):

you can see this question [How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder) , which is pretty similar to your question or watch this sample code from apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html