# How to Record Audio in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, audio, record

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to record audio through an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602901/how-to-record-audio-through-an-iphone-app)

I want to record audio in iphone app for 10 sec, then how to record a audio for given time limit.