# send voice message using objective-c iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, message, voice

Is there any way to send recorded voice in message programmatically using objective-c and iPhone.

I am sending text message using messageUI framework but now I want to send voice message too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing straightforward built for voice messages built into iOS, unlike "`MFMessageComposeViewController`".  You'll have to write your own voice recording code or make use of something open source or third party/commercial. [Here's a related question that talks about how to record audio through iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602901/how-to-record-audio-through-an-iphone-app).

Plus this depends on *how* you want the recipient to receive the recorded voice message?  A mp3 or some other audio file sent via e-mail (which you can do using the MFMailComposeViewCOntroller) or some other way?