# How to increase volume of sound recorded using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am using the link mentioned below to record audio through my iPhone app:

[How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)

When I try to play my recordings using AVAudioPlayer on my device, I have seen that the sound volume of my recordings is very low even when my device volume is full.

Recording is working fine.

What can be done to increase the volume?

Comment: This should not have been marked as a duplicate IMO; the "duplicate" question has answers in Objective C, while the answer provided here is Swift related

Comment: +1 for not a duplicate. This is asking specifically about playback volume not the generic "How do I record stuff" question linked.

Answer (score 41):

When recording audio, set the audio session to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` or just `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord`. When you're done, set it back to just `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`.

Comment: Category is already set to AVAudioSessionPlayAndRecord. I have posted the link I am using. I am using the same code as given there by @unforgiven so may be you can see there and give some suggestions.

Comment: Right, so when you're done, set it back to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback. That will make the sound louder. For some reason, playback and recording at the same time reduces the volume, probably because doing both requires more battery power.

Comment: The volume difference may also be to help prevent feedback from the speaker back into the microphone when simultaneously recording and playing.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have set volume level to 1.0 however it works fine in iPad. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Solution for **iOS 12 + Swift 5.0**:

- When *starting* recording use:

  `recordingSession.setCategory(.record)` // recordingSession is of type AVAudioSession
- When *playing* the record audio use:

  `recordingSession.setCategory(.playback)`

Note: Place the statements into a do-catch block.

Answer (score -1):

you can try `AVaudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker)` 
this is because your output device set to inbuilt speaker in iPhone.
while iTab have only speaker so no problem occurs.