# AVAudioRecorder : Are there any other reasons to decrease the volume of recorded audio?

Tags: ios, audio, audio-recording

I'm developing a video editing app which includes audio/video recording feature.

I faced an issue like the links below, but none of the solutions work and I'm stuck.

Of course I've tried setting AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord and AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker which is proposed in the below links.

[How to increase volume of sound recorded using AVAudioRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654014/how-to-increase-volume-of-sound-recorded-using-avaudiorecorder)
[Low recording volume in combination with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246374/low-recording-volume-in-combination-with-avaudiosessioncategoryplayandrecord)

On top of that I have checked the recorded audio's volume with external audio editing tool(Audacity on Mac) and compared to the audio which was recorded with simple audio recorder app [Audio Recording using AVAudioRecorder](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/). The wave height of my app's audio is lower by approx. 20dB.

Normally thinking I'm doing something else to lower my recording volume without notice, but I cannot find anything else to affect the recorded volume.

Are there any other things I have to check around the audio recording settings or any operations which may reduce the recorded audio volume?

Comment: What was your solution to this issue?

Comment: Actually no solution so far.  I end up with raising the volume by postprocessing. But the quality gets pretty bad.  I'm still looking for the solution.