# Where is my recorded audio file and what is its default type in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, audio

I'm recording a file using `AVAudioSession` but i do not know where its stored and with which file format .wav or .mp3 :P ? Could someone help me? Also I need to know mimetype?

Comment: please someone help :( i m real stuck

Comment: Do you use AVAudioRecorder or only AVAudioSession ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the destination path of the recording (usually the documents directory of your app)
In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder) you'll find the code you need.