# How to play record the sound programmatically and how to play that recorded audio?

Tags: iphone, playback

I am developing one application. In that I want to record the sounds and I want to play that recorded sound file. I know the frameworks for doing this. But how to develop programmatically by using that frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this link:

I have implemented this code in one of my apps and it works completely fine.

[How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)

For Playing the sound you have option to use AVAudioRecorder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it - and I am talking from painful experience here - is with the RemoteIO audio unit. You can also do it with AudioQueue, but it has a higher latency, and the queue type approach becomes very problematic.

So, I think that they are really different tools for different jobs. Note that you won't play a sound file as such. You will play the contents of a buffer held in memory. As long as the buffer is not too large, this should not be an issue.

So, going with RemoteIO, you will find this blog and tutorial very useful. It includes code samples.

[Using RemoteIO audio unit By MICHAEL TYSON](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/)