# Playing sound while recording

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudiosession

Is it possible to play back a sound while it is recording it, live?

I found this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder) which shows how to record sound with AVAudioSession.

If so, at what should I be looking at? Can AVAudioSession play sound as well?

*(Basically like an amplifier, outputting the sound as it comes in)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either the Audio Queue API or the RemoteIO Audio Unit for streaming audio record and play.  The RemoteIO unit will have a much lower latency.  Either way, you should initialize your audio session and set it for kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord.