# how to get the sound dB by using cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, audio

i want to get the sound dB when I am talking. If the sound dB is high enough, the record function will run, so how can i get the sound dB? many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)

Comment: cocos2d/coosdenshion has no audio recording support: http://cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion:faq#can_i_record_audio_data_with_cocosdenshion

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AVAudioPlayer, then, I think you can use the below to return the following values in dB's:

```
double peakPower =[audioPlayer peakPowerForChannel:0];
double avgPower = [audioPlayer averagePowerForChannel:0];
```