# this app was developed and works fine under ios 5.0, but crashes under ios 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, avaudiosession

I developed an iPhone app under iOS 5.0, and it works fine. But when it comes to iOS 4.3(Base SDK = latest iOS 5.0, compiler = Apple LLVM 3.0, Deployment Target = iOS 4.3), it crashes after launching.

The output around crash point looks like:

```
2011-12-06 16:25:08.177 FMWei[466:c203] -[AVAudioSession setMode:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x706a7f0
2011-12-06 16:25:08.181 FMWei[466:c203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVAudioSession setMode:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x706a7f0'
```

It looks like that `AVAudioSession` doesn't have a member function `setMode:error:` while I invoked it. But what's strange is that I didn't invoke a function whose name is `setMode:error:`. The code about audio processing is:

```
audio_session = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] retain];
audio_session_err = nil;
[audio_session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&audio_session_err];
NSLog(@"!");

UInt32 audioRouteOverride = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
UInt32 allowMixing = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);    

if (audio_session_err) 
{
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [audio_session_err domain], [audio_session_err code], [audio_session_err description]);
}
else
{
    audio_session_err = nil;
    [audio_session setActive:YES error:&audio_session_err];
    if (!audio_session_err) NSLog(@"audio session is activated successfully");
}
```

Please help me figure out why it crashes under iOS 4.3 with the strange error. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At runtime, lots of methods are called that are not in your code, but which are called behind the scenes as a result of the API calls you have made.

I would focus not on the method that is being called, but on why the object it is sent to is unable to respond to the selector. The object could have been cast as the wrong type, and so is not inheriting the right methods. (In the code snippet you show, you don't explicitly cast `AVAudioSession *audio_session`.) The other direction is to check that you're not using some other API call that is iOS 5 only, which in the background is calling this method and thus generating the error.

Finally, if you're only recently changed your build target to include iOS 4.3, you may simply need to do a clean build (Product > Clean) so that it compiles iOS 4.3-compatible code.

Comment: Thank you Duncan:-) there is a `NSError *audio_session_err;` in the .h file.

Comment: I casted `AVAudioSession *audio_session;` in the .h file, sorry for that I did't show that.

Comment: is it possible that the AVFoundation.framework file which I included is for iOS 5.0 only, and it invokes something unfriendly? How can I include the older version of these frameworks?

Comment: Hmm, that raises an interesting possibility. If you're only recently changed your app to include iOS 4.3 as your build target, try a clean build...

Comment: amazing...don't know what to say then, i am stupid...please modify the answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @Skyler As requested, I've updated my answer to include my recommendation in the comments that you try a clean build. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try the code snippet below

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
NSError * audio_session_err = nil;
[audio_session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&audio_session_err];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&audio_session_err];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
NSLog(@"!");

UInt32 audioRouteOverride = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
UInt32 allowMixing = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);    

if (audio_session_err) {
  NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [audio_session_err domain], [audio_session_err code], [audio_session_err description]);
} else {
  audio_session_err = nil;
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&audio_session_err];
  if (!audio_session_err) NSLog(@"audio session is activated successfully");
}
```

I think `audio_session = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] retain];` dispatchs the method `setMode:` by default. And the `setMode:` is only available in iOS 5.0 and later(refer to the [`Doc`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Modes)).

Or you can try to comment out the code:

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
UInt32 allowMixing = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);
```

There must be a method dispatches the `setMode:` by default. Try yourself. :p

---

Try `info malloc 0x706a7f0` in your gdb to get the object that the selector was sent to. Note, the `0x706a7f0` is the address that shown in your crash output as the one in your first code snippet.

And another tip, you might do `make clean`(Poduct->Clean) and `rebuild` it.

Comment: @Skyler Maybe you should not retain the `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]`. Look [`HERE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder) ;)

Comment: thank you:-) I have tried not to retain it, but it crashed all the same.

Comment: I tried your snippet and also comment out the C code just now. it crashes with the same error :-(

Comment: Hi @Skyler, I saw you have add some NSLog in your code. Can you show what have been print before the app crashed?

Comment: Thank you @Kjuly, the target output nothing before crash. It looks like crashed before runtime because I have a couple of NSLog in the `AppicationDidFinishLaunching`, but still nothing output. besides, the debugger output A LOT OF warning about 'more recent than executable timestamp' or 'Could not open OSO file to scan for pubtypes for objfile'

Comment: @Skyler try `info malloc 0x706a7f0` in your gdb to get the object that the selector was sent to. Note, the `0x706a7f0` is the address that shown in your crash output as the one in your first code snippet. And another tip, you might do `make clean`(Poduct->Clean) and rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

The `AVAudioSession` method

```
- (BOOL)setMode:(NSString *)theMode error:(NSError **)outError
```

Is marked in the documentation as being available only for iOS 5 and later. In fact given the [recent addition of modes to the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240-CH99-SW1), it looks like audio session modes are not available at all prior to iOS 5.

Comment: You could try a symbolic break point to work out where it's being called from in your code.

Comment: I added a symbolic break point to `-[AVAudioSession setMode:error:]` but nothing changed.it crashes as before.

Comment: The symbolic break point wasn't intended to stop the crash, but rather to clarify the exact line in _your_ code that was leading to that method being called. :)

Comment: hmm...indeed it clarified nothing. it looks like crashed before runtime. I added some NSLog in the `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching` but nothing output.