# iOS background audio linker error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avplayer

error;

```
undefined symbols for architecture i386:
    "_AudioSessionSetProperty", referenced from:
    -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in AppDelegate.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

code i am using:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Set AudioSession
    NSError *sessionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&sessionError];

    /* Pick any one of them */
    // 1. Overriding the output audio route
    //UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    //AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(audioRouteOverride), &audioRouteOverride);

    // 2. Changing the default output audio route
    UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);

    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

(from https://devforums.apple.com/thread/90684?start=0&tstart=0 and [this app was developed and works fine under ios 5.0, but crashes under ios 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397223/this-app-was-developed-and-works-fine-under-ios-5-0-but-crashes-under-ios-4-3) and [How do I get my AVPlayer to play while app is in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771105/how-do-i-get-my-avplayer-to-play-while-app-is-in-background))

finally my plist:

[image]
what is the issue? in my header of appdelegate:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

}
```

seems that everything is imported. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: did u include AudioToolbox to the application?,if yes then once remove and  again
Add the AudioToolbox and AVFoundation frameworks to your project by Right-Cliking on Frameworks -> Add -> Existing Frameworks

Comment: wow that was strange... it showed the framework on the left but it wasnt in my build phases. builds now! thx!

Comment: it still doesnt play audio in the background, at least on the simulator though

Comment: for playing audio which code u r using?

Comment: i mean can u post the code?

Comment: https://pastee.org/b7796 is the code. thx so much!

Comment: once go through this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it to play audio in the background:

```
// Allow to play in background
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

also this fixed the above bug:

Add the AudioToolbox and AVFoundation frameworks to your project by Right-Cliking on Frameworks -> Add -> Existing Frameworks