# AvAudioRecorder recording file corrupted randomly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avaudiorecorder

I face issue with AvAudioRecorder, create corrupted file on random check.

It create file with length 24kb, which is not occurred all time, but randomly found file is corrupted.

I also checked below link for references, as i have similar issue, but it does not worked for me.

[AVAudioRecorder Record method returns NO at random times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706020/avaudiorecorder-record-method-returns-no-at-random-times)

[Seemingly random file corruption using AVAudioRecorder (Sometimes the file can't be played back) - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704827/seemingly-random-file-corruption-using-avaudiorecorder-sometimes-the-file-cant)

below is complete functionality code.

```
-(IBAction)btnRecordClick:(id)sender
{
    [PlayingTimer invalidate];
    PlayingTimer = nil;

    if(isPaused==NO)
    {
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];

        if(err)
        {
            // NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
            return;
        }

        [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
        err = nil;

        if(err)
        {
            // NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
            return;
        }

        //*******Working well with .wav,.caf and .mp4 files *****************
        recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        //this is for .wav and .caf file
        //this is for .mp4 file for iPhone 3GS/iPhone 4
        [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];

        self.strMessage = @"";
        self.strMessageType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Audio Message"];
        self.strFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4", [_globalmodel stringUniqueID]];
        // NSLog(@"FileName :%@",self.strFileName);

        self.strUniqueRef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_globalmodel stringUniqueID]];

        NSString *soundPath;//=[NSString alloc];
        soundPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER,self.strFileName] ;
        NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

        // NSLog(@"Recording Path:%@",url1);
        err = nil;
        recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url1 settings:recordSetting error:&err];

        if(!recorder)
        {
            // NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
            UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"My Easy Media"
                                                           message: @"The Recording format is not supported on your device!"
                                                          delegate: nil
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];

            return;
        }

        //prepare to record
        [recorder setDelegate:self];
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;

        if (! audioHWAvailable)
        {
            UIAlertView *cantRecordAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
                                                                      message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
                                                                     delegate: nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [cantRecordAlert show];
            [cantRecordAlert release];

            return;
        }

        // start recording
        [recorder record];
        _isRecordingStarted = YES;

        // SET TIMER // START TIMER
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(EndRecording:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        // END TO SETTING TIMER
        timerDisplayRight.hidden = NO;
        timerDisplayLeft.hidden = NO;
        timerDisplayRight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", intMimute,-- intSecond]; 
        timerDisplayLeft.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:00"];
        progressView.progress = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        isPaused=NO;
        [recorder record];   
        _isRecordingStarted = YES;
        [btnReview setEnabled:NO];

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(EndRecording:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        timerDisplayRight.hidden = NO;
        timerDisplayLeft.hidden = NO;
    }

    timerDisplayRight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", intMimute,-- intSecond];
}


-(IBAction)btnPauseClick:(id)sender
{
    // NSLog(@"Pause Button of ActionSheet Clicked");
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    isPaused=YES;
    [recorder pause];

    [btnPause setEnabled:NO];
    [btnRecord setEnabled:YES];
    [btnStop setEnabled:YES];
}


-(IBAction)btnStopClick:(id)sender
{
    // NSLog(@"Stop Button of ActionSheet Clicked");
    [recorder stop];

    progressView.progress = 1.0;
    // NSLog(@"Total Recording Secomd : %d", totalRecordingSecond);
    finalRecordingSecond = totalRecordingSecond;

    [btnStop setEnabled:NO];
    [btnReview setEnabled:YES];
    [btnRecord setEnabled:YES];
    [btnPause setEnabled:NO];

    timerDisplayRight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", (totalRecordingSecond/60), (totalRecordingSecond % 60) ];
    timerDisplayLeft.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:00"];

    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;

    // REINITIALIZE TIMER VARIABLES...
    intMimute =  5;
    intTotalTime = (60 * intMimute);   
    intSecond = intTotalTime / intMimute;
    intMimute--;       

    // REINITIALIZE TIMER VARIABLES...       
    _isRecordingStarted = NO;
}
```

Please help. Once I start recording and after near about 10 to 15 second, tap on stop.

Comment: Have you found the reason? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it happen when any run any process in background in separate thread, same time when recording.

Comment: Please verify it is the problem or u think it was the problem. I am facing same kind of problem when i record audio in 15-20 files 1-2 files get corrupted