# Record the sound through AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I want to record the sound and want to save the recorded file into document directory:-
Had done Like:-

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
         setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord
         error: nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        recorderFilePath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Audio.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER] retain];
        NSURL *soundFileURL=[NSURL URLWithString:recorderFilePath];

    recorderFilePath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Audio.caf", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER] retain];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recorderFilePath];


        NSLog(@"str==>%@ soundurl==>%@",recorderFilePath,soundFileURL);
        AVAudioRecorder *newRecorder =
        [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: url
                                    settings: settings
                                       error: nil];

 newRecorder.delegate = self;
        [newRecorder prepareToRecord];
        [newRecorder record];
```

and [recorder stop]; when stop recording is done.

Had seen this :- 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)

and coded accordingly..But still i am not able to create any .caf file into the document folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once go through below code it might be helpful to you.
First take object for AVAudioRecorder as  AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    //here i took cache directory as saved directory you can also take   NSDocumentDirectory
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];//at this path your recorded audio will be saved

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,

                                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,

                                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,

                                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

    if( !audioRecorder ) {

        UIAlertView *alert  =
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning" message: [error localizedDescription] delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;

    }

    if ( error )
    {
        NSLog( @"error: %@", [error localizedDescription] );
    }
    else {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
        [self recordAudio];//Mehod to Record Audio
    }

}
```

Now define method to record Audio,

```
 -(void) recordAudio
 {
     if (!audioRecorder.recording)
      {
       audioRecorder.delegate = self;
      [audioRecorder recordForDuration:10];//Here i took record duration as 10 secs 

     }
```

}

Now you can write AvAudio record DelegateMethods as,

```
-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:      (BOOL)flag
 {
  //Your code after sucessful recording;
 }
-(void)audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder error:(NSError *)error
 {
NSLog(@"Encode Error occurred");
}
```

hope it will helps to you...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I try using this..and the sound file also get created..but not able to hear any sound from that file

Comment: sorry,once record the audio and play the audio file named sound.caf at cachedirectory

Comment: Yes i had player the sound.caf from quick player.But not able to hear anything

Comment: make sure your sound is not in mute.because this code i hv used here and working fine for me

Comment: hv u got audio with 10 sec duration?

Comment: Yes.I got the audio of 10sec and size 1.8MB.Its playing for 10sec..But no sound is been there..I make sure and nothing is been set as mute

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26145/discussion-between-shweta-and-murali)

Comment: sry to ask but hv u recorded any Audio

Comment: yes.I do recorded the some voice..Is it working fine at ur end.I am trying to record the sound by headphone mic in simulater

Comment: once go through this link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder

Comment: @shweta: did you achieved this ?