# iOS: call native audio recorder

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to record/play audio on my app. There is anyway to just "call" the native record of iOS, and get the record after done? So, I don't need to develop entire new xib to microphone.
Like on Android, that your app can call the microphone's app and get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know, there's no any way to call native audio record from your app.

Short answer, check this out - [Speak here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/)

Be sure to check this thread - [How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder) it's pretty old question though.

Comment: So, I have to develop my own UI? That's horrible

Comment: you have a example 'Speak here'. It should be pretty simple, give it a chance

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVAudioRecorder.

Google will give you some examples. Here is one -

[How do I record audio on iPhone with AVAudioRecorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010343/how-do-i-record-audio-on-iphone-with-avaudiorecorder)

You will have to make your own UI for it though.