# save multiple recording audio files and fetch all recording audios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I am working on audio recording using AVAudiofoundation,audio is storing and playing properly, But my problem is i have to record multiple audios and i have to show that in table, Now i am getting one url address only. please help me to find the solution.

This button is showing for paused the audio recording,i think here i want to do some thing for my problem

```
    - (IBAction)recordPauseTapped:(id)sender
    {
        // Stop the audio player before recording
        if (player.playing)
        {
            [player stop];
        }

        if (!recorder.recording)
        {
            AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
            [session setActive:YES error:nil];
            // Start recording
            [recorder record];
            [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            // Pause recording
            [recorder pause];
            [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

        [stopButton setEnabled:YES];
        [playButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
```

this button is for stop the recording

```
    - (IBAction)stopTapped:(id)sender
    {
        [recorder stop];
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
        NSString *urr=[recorder.url absoluteString];
        [recordeddata addObject:urr];

    }
```

This button is for play the recorded audio

```
    - (IBAction)playTapped:(id)sender {
        if (!recorder.recording)
        {
             player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
            [player setDelegate:self];
            [player play];
            [_tableview reloadData];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code with which you are saving the file, and accessing the audio file, the above code has nothing to do with file fetching.

Comment: i posted again,see at down please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the audio recorder with only one file path, So you can only save one audio at a time

```
NSMutableArray *pathComponents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                           nil];
```

make this name `MyAudioMemo.m4a` dynamic,

when you want to record a new audio

```
- (int)numberOfFilesInDocPath
{
    NSString *docPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *filelist= [filemgr directoryContentsAtPath: docPath];
    int count = [filelist count];
    return count;
}
- (void)recordNewAudioWithFileName
{
    int numberOfFiles = [self numberOfFilesInDocPath];
    NSString *newFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyAudioMemo_%d.m4a",numberOfFiles];
    NSMutableArray *pathComponents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                                  newFileName,
                                  nil];
     NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];


    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];


}
```

For entire implementation, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1011273/3733561)

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    recordeddata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    // Disable Stop/Play button when application launches
    [stopButton setEnabled:NO];
    [playButton setEnabled:NO];

    // Set the audio file
    NSMutableArray *pathComponents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];

    _tableview.dataSource=self;
    _tableview.delegate=self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)recordPauseTapped:(id)sender
{
    // Stop the audio player before recording
    if (player.playing)
    {
        [player stop];
    }

    if (!recorder.recording)
    {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive:YES error:nil];
        // Start recording
        [recorder record];
        [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        // Pause recording
        [recorder pause];
        [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [stopButton setEnabled:YES];
    [playButton setEnabled:NO];
}

- (IBAction)stopTapped:(id)sender
{
    [recorder stop];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
    NSString *urr=[recorder.url absoluteString];
    [recordeddata addObject:urr];

}

- (IBAction)playTapped:(id)sender {
    if (!recorder.recording)
    {
         player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
        [_tableview reloadData];
    }
}

#pragma mark - AVAudioRecorderDelegate

- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avrecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    [recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [stopButton setEnabled:NO];
    [playButton setEnabled:YES];    
}

#pragma mark - AVAudioPlayerDelegate

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                               message: @"Finish playing the recording!"
                              delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return recordeddata.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[recordeddata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *str=[recordeddata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
    if (!recorder.recording)
    {
        player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }
}
```