# iPhone, record sounds from speaker and microphone simultaneously

Tags: ios, recording

I'm trying to record sounds from a speaker and microphone simultaneously in iPhone. I used AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioSession to do this, but it doesn't work: the only sound recorded is from the microphone.

I've already read articles about this on stackoverflow, like [Record AVAudioPlayer output using AVAudioRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970416/record-avaudioplayer-output-using-avaudiorecorder?rq=1) and similar questions and answers.

Are there any good references or classes to implement this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to record sound from the speaker?

Comment: Do you want to play sound from the speaker and record from the microphone simultaneously? Because a speaker by definition does not record sound...

Comment: @H2CO3 let assume that sound from speaker is a music and audio from microphone is my voice.

Comment: @qegal no, record sound output to speaker and sound input from microphone simultaneously.

Comment: You already have the bits for the audio that you are playing through the speaker, so the real question here is how can I mix the recording and the microphone audio and sync the time. I would re-ask or edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

if we want to use both of them at a time we need to set AVAudioSession's Category to AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient.

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```