# Record voice call in android, ios and windows apps

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I want to develop app to record audio in .mp3 format. It has to record a voice call, a meeting etc.

I searched and found few sample code for android which works for recording only single track(microphone). How can i record sound coming from microphone as well as speaker(in case of voice calls). And how can I achieve this in ios and windows?

Here is what I tried in Android. This works and creates .mp3 file , but any help recording a voice call?

```
   string path = "/sdcard/test.mp3";
   MediaRecorder _recorder = new MediaRecorder();
   _recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Mpeg4);
   _recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Aac);
   _recorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(44100);
   _recorder.SetAudioEncodingBitRate(8000);
   _recorder.SetOutputFile(path);
   _recorder.Prepare();
   _recorder.Start();
```

iOS code (creates a file but doesn't play or does not create file properly):

```
// Declare string for application temp path and tack on the file extension
string fileName = string.Format("Myfile{0}.aac", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
string tempRecording = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);

Console.WriteLine(tempRecording);
this.audioFilePath = NSUrl.FromFilename(tempRecording);

//set up the NSObject Array of values that will be combined with the keys to make the NSDictionary
NSObject[] values = new NSObject[]
{    
    NSNumber.FromFloat(44100.0f),
    NSNumber.FromInt32((int)AudioToolbox.AudioFormatType.MPEG4AAC),
    NSNumber.FromInt32(1),
    NSNumber.FromInt32((int)AVAudioQuality.High)
};
//Set up the NSObject Array of keys that will be combined with the values to make the NSDictionary
NSObject[] keys = new NSObject[]
{
    AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey,
    AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey,
    AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
    AVAudioSettings.AVEncoderAudioQualityKey
};
//Set Settings with the Values and Keys to create the NSDictionary
settings = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(values, keys);

//Set recorder parameters
NSError error;
recorder = AVAudioRecorder.Create(this.audioFilePath, new AudioSettings(settings), out error);
```

Any help in recording voice calls in .mp3 format on ios and android. Or recording simple .mp3 file in iOS for start.

I would also like to know if I get a list of SamplingRate, BitRate, AudioEncoder in android and iOS?

Comment: for iOS, refer this links. https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=KDAPV6PpFeqK8QfNkKHgAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=ios+record+voice+from+speaker+output. Mostly this ans will solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970416/record-avaudioplayer-output-using-avaudiorecorder?rq=1

Comment: and why do you tag a question with Android if you need to do something with iOS?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I want to achieve this for all the platforms android, ios and windows.

Comment: but you did already for Android, didn't you? Do you have any problems with Android?

Comment: I managed to record audio(mp3) file, but no luck recording voice call --Android